# Low quality/Blurry Images and textures

Tags: mesh, texturing, materials, image

Whenever I import images or textures into blender, they are super blurry and low quality. I have tried uninstalling and downloading the newest version of Blender but still nothing[image]

Comment: Maybe because when it is imported it will be Linear by Default in the Image Texture node, instead try Closest

Comment: it works but I cant do that for referance images

Comment: Oh yes you're right, maybe you should specify that it's a Reference image

Comment: Your post shows a plane mesh with a shader, not a image reference, it's quite misleading. You do not have access to textures' interpolation from image references, so you must use plane meshes and shaders to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because you imported the image as a plane, try importing it as a reference or background.

Comment: Still doesnt work :D

Comment: All the images you tried to import got this problem?

Comment: yeah none of them work

Comment: sorry i don't really know why this happens to you